# How can I creat a static variable which returns the last array index, in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I want to create a function which a static variable because I need to preserve the variable value between functions. The first way, this variable include the last index an array, and the value will be changed the second run. If I use count() to search the last array index, I get the following error: Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or`';'' in C:\wamp\www\rekurzio\index.php on line 11

```
<form method="POST">
    Search the following number: <input type="number" name="numberQuestion">! <br>
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
</form>

<?php function search(){
            global $numberArray;
            $numberQuestion = $_POST['numberQuestion'];
            static $searchDirection = "RIGHT";
            static $lowerLimit = 0; //it is the first array index
            static $upperLimit = count($numberArray)-1 /* 8 */; //it is the last array index, but it doesn't work
            if($lowerLimit == $numberQuestion){
                $searchResult = "I found the $numberQuestion value which the $lowerLimit element";
                echo $searchResult;
            }else if($upperLimit == $numberQuestion){
                $searchResult = "I found the $numberQuestion value which the $upperLimit element";
                echo $searchResult;
            }else{
                $middleElement = ($lowerLimit+$upperLimit)/2;
                if($middleElement == $numberQuestion){
                    $searchResult = "I found the $numberQuestion value which the $middleElement element";
                    echo $searchResult;
                }else{
                    if($numberQuestion < $middleElement){
                        $searchDirection = "LEFT";
                    }else if($numberQuestion > $middleElement){
                        $searchDirection = "RIGHT";
                    }
                    if($searchDirection == "RIGHT"){
                        $lowerLimit = $middleElement;
                    }else if($searchDirection == "LEFT"){
                        $upperLimit = $middleElement;
                    }
                    search();
                }
            }               
        }           
        if(isset($_POST['search'])){
            search();
        } ?>
```

How can I search the last array index?

Answer (score 3):

Static declarations are resolved in compile-time, therefore trying to assign values to these variables which are the result of expressions will cause a parse error. For reference, see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static).

So static variables may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed. While you may initialize a static variable to an integer or array (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a function return value, or to an object.

**UPDATE:**
In your case I would advise that the 3 static-scoped variables (`$searchDirection`, `$lowerLimit` and `$upperLimit`) be function parameters instead of static variables. In this case their scope is still local to the `search` function, however you may dynamically set the proper values before the initial and then the recursive calls of the function.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand now, but I still have the problem: how can I preserve the status between two function calls?

Comment: I extended my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I could not comment because I do not have enough reputations.

I suggest you do two things:

First:  convert line 11 into 
`static $upperLimit = count($numberArray)-1; /* 8 */`

Second, do `var_dump($numberArray);` before the line above. It seems that there is some sort of simple syntax error over there.